# What amount can be paid at the end of every month in perpetuity from an endowment of $350,000 which is earning 5.4% compounded monthly?

Tags: arithmetic

What amount can be paid at the end of every month in perpetuity from 
an endowment of $350,000 which is earning 5.4% compounded 
monthly?

Am trying to apply the compound interest formula but it isn't working

Comment: Please elaborate on "trying to apply the compound interest formula".

Comment: I thought it was a case of compounding using the formula A=P(1+r/n)^nt but seem not to have time

Comment: What do you mean "seem not to have time"???

Comment: in the formula, we have A for amount, P for principal, r for rate which is 5.4 n is 12 but time t is not given. I somehow think this is not the appropriate formula for this case

Comment: @Ben Do you have any additional information that indicates it is required to use devaluation schemes like "present value"? Or is it a simple "sum $x$ generates $p$ percent interest every month" task?

Comment: @mvw Your statements are not really a contradiction. You sum up the all compounded payments (a). Then you have the future value. But 350.000 is a present value. Thus we have to calculate the summed compounded payments and discount it n times. Then we have an equality.

Comment: You just need the monthly interest rate. Obviously the endowment remains permanently at 350000 and all the interest is paid out monthly. Presumably 5.4% is an annualised rate, so you have to convert to a monthly rate. So $1.054^{1/12}-1=0.439\%$ giving a monthly payout of 1538.

Answer (score 1):

The present value of the sum of  a monthly paid annuity ($a$) after $n$ years is

$PV=a\cdot \frac{(1+0.054/12)^n-1}{0.054/12}\cdot \frac{1}{(1+0.054/12)^n}$

Let $n$ go to infinity

$\lim_{n \to \infty}PV=\frac{a}{\frac{0.054}{12}}=a\cdot222.222$

Thus the equation is $350,000=a\cdot222.222$

$a=1575$

Comment: Present value seems to be a concept to quantify the idea that getting money today is more useful than tomorrow.  I see no such thing requested in the question.

Comment: 350.000 is a kind of present value. So we have to find the present value of the perpetuity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the amount can not be more than the monthly earning of
$$
m = 350000 \cdot 5.4/100 = 18900
$$
Otherwise the generating sum would shrink month by month and vanish within finite time.

I would also assume that the monthly payment is assumed to stay the same every month. Otherwise the problem is probably not uniquely solvable.

Comment: Your solution is not right.

Comment: An amazing investment if it is returning 5.4% monthly! The approach is correct, but you have to convert to a monthly return. We have to assume that 5.45% is an annualised figure.

Comment: I took it because of the "5.4% compounded monthly", It is an unrealistic high rate, indeed.